# Spring-kafka high volume processing

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

Using spring-kafka 1.0.5, I am consuming from a busy topic with 10 partitions with a concurrency of 10.

My current code adds a message to a queue based on the partition ID which are both persisted in a HashMap.

```
@KafkaListener(topics = "${kafka.topic}")
public void onMessage(ConsumerRecord consumerRecord, Acknowledgment acknowledgment) {
    //Pseudo code
    add to Hashmap<Integer, Queue<ConsumerRecord>> based on partition.
}
```

Unfortunately, that design is taking twice the processing time a simple consumption would take.

My requirement is to process **partitions separately** but how can avoid having a hashmap with a reference to a partition based on the @KafkaListener.

Is there a more efficient way of going about this? Ideally, each thread from the listener annotation would manage its own list. Is there a way to do that without having a cross reference such as the hashmap mentioned above based on the partition ID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider to declare several `@KafkaListener` methods for each of your required partition. For this purpose you should use `topicPartitions` attribute instead of `topics`:

```
/**
 * Used to add topic/partition information to a {@code KafkaListener}.
 *
 */
@Target({})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface TopicPartition {
```

Comment: What would happen on re-balancing?

Comment: Rebalancing happens when you have several consumers for the same `partition`. It has nothing common with the `topic`.

Comment: Unfortunately, we've experienced re-balancing on network hiccups.

Comment: Well, so you have several `@KafkaListener` s for the same partition or just for the whole topic and some of them are slow.

Comment: I would like to avoid having my applications be aware of the partitions they are consuming from. Is it possible to have multiple @KafkaListeners for the same topic within my application consuming from a single partition?

Comment: ??? But your `add to Hashmap<Integer, Queue<ConsumerRecord>> based on partition.` is exactly about *aware*. You have to configure `@TopicPartition` if a discussion is about one partition from topic and ignoring all others.

Comment: What I meant by that is I would like to avoid having one application consume from Partition 1 specifically for example. I would like my consumers to be able to consume from any partition on re-balancing or restart but the hashmap would track the list for that partition.

Comment: Let me rephrase my previous question. Is it possible to have multiple @KafkaListeners without assigning them to a specific partition in my application with each assigned to a single partition consuming from the same topic?

Comment: No, that isn't possible. See `KafkaConsumer.subscribe()` which is used when you don't specify particular partitions to consume.

Comment: You can try to configure `ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory.concurrency` to `10` to be able to have a whole distribution during rebalance.

Comment: Thank you. The problem for a specific partition assignment is recovery. If a server goes down, we would like re-balancing to be handled automatically. We would run the risk for a partition to not be consumed if a server assigned to that partition was down.

Comment: That doesn't matter. If there are several consumers in the same group for the same partition, only one consumes. When that is dead the rebalance should be applied anyway automatically for the rest of consumers in the group. No? Am I missing something ?

Comment: "If there are several consumers in the same group for the same partition". That would work indeed. I was thinking about each consumer assigned to unique partition (example: 5 consumers with 2 partitions each only). So you recommend having 10 @KafkaListener with concurrency of 10 with each thread managing its own list in each application?

Comment: Not sure what is "each application", but I suggested two variants: 10 `@KafkaListener` for each partition. And another one `@KafkaListener` for the whole topic, but with the 10 `concurrency`. In both cases each partition will be handled by its own thread.

Comment: We are planning on having multiple applications listening to the Kafka topic. Thank you for your time, you've clarified a few things.

Comment: That's good, indeed. Only the problem to configure all those application into one `consumer group`. That way you have single consumer at a time and automatic rebalance.